# Filtering a matrix in R by matching it a list

Tags: r, filter, merge

I have the matrix:

```
traits <- matrix(c(1,0,1, 1,0,0, 0,0,0), nrow = 3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE,
           dimnames = list(c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3"),c("Tr1", "Tr2", "Tr3")))
```

and a list

```
species <-c("sp1", "sp2")
```

how can I filter the 'traits' matrix so it returns just the matches i.e.

```
traits.filtered<-matrix(c(1,0, 1,1, 0,0), nrow = 2, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE,
           dimnames = list(c("sp1", "sp2"),c("Tr1", "Tr2", "Tr3")))
```

Thank you,
-Elizabeth

Comment: You can index a matrix by its rownames. In your case, try  `traits[species,].`

Comment: Elizabeth, you mention data frame repeatedly, but show an matrix example. Can you clarify which it is so we/you can tidy the Question.

Comment: Good point @GavinSimpson I have edited the question so that it is clear I am working with a matrix and a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious approach is to subset the `traits` matrix using `species` as follows:

```
traits[species, ]
```

However, this only works assuming that the row names are unique - if they're not, only the first match is returned.

For that reason, I'd strongly recommended using the more robust:

```
traits[rownames(traits) %in% species, ]
```

Comment: Rownames for dataframes are _supposed_ to be unique. When you create doubled rows with ordinary functions,  the row.names get sequence numbers append, so I worry that your "more robust" method might be actually more fragile.

Comment: A rare point where our views differ! :) The OP is using a matrix (rightly or wrongly - separate issue), so there's no reason to assume the row names are unique - indeed, they could well be duplicated explicitly in the definition of `traits`. And of course, combining matrices doesn't give rise to "sequence numbers". In fairness I don't think there's any fragility in my solution: if someone wishes to do a match on row names (which personally feels like an awkward idea anyway - I'd always opt for a dedicated column... but anyway), it's their responsibility to get the row names right, not mine! :)

Comment: Ah. He said 'dataframe' (four times actually) and then used a matrix. If he will be using a matrix then your point is valid.

Comment: Tim P This should have been a comment to either my or @ttmaccer answers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @DWin. I meant matrix throughout and have edited my question appropriately. Tim Ps solution worked a treat. Thank you

Comment: @GavinSimpson. No idea what you're talking about. I was responding to DWin's comment in this thread.

Comment: @TimP Sorry; "This" should have been "Your Answer". Coming a number of hours after ttmaccer's Answer, your contribution was really a comment on the optimality of the two Answers provided at that stage. Things like that should be posted as comments, not new Answers. I should have made it clear to what I was referring.

Comment: @GavinSimpson. Hi, so I must admit to not quite understanding the problem. What are the rules for proffering your answer to a question? What I submitted is the answer I would have given anyway without looking at either of the other responses - there are two obvious commands that work, but one has shortcomings. I had a scan of what else was there and no-one had noted this, so I added something to the debate (I thought) by submitting my answer. By this point about 30 seconds had passed, I didn't really dwell on it. I mean, it wasn't something designed to cause aggro - it's just an answer, man!

Comment: @DWin, cool, thanks, maybe our views don't really differ then. If it was a data frame, I'd agree with everything you said!

Comment: I think the issue that @gavinsimpson is referring to, is that your answer is written in the format of a comment, not an answer.Keep in mind that answers will migrate up or down the stack, depending on how many votes they attract. So, although the code in your answer is perfectly fine, it somehow seems to inherently comments on a different answer. Perhaps just this answer so it stand s by itself?

Comment: @TimP In this case both answers already provided covered the points in your Answer so at that point, some hours after they were posted it might have been better to just comment on ttmaccer's Answer re the point about robustness. To be honest, ttmacer's Answer isn't a great SO Answer as it is just code with no explanation; it is right/valid but does no more than give a solution. It doesn't help SO if there are too many "me too" answers as that detracts from overall SO resource. In this case I may retract my objection only because ttmacer's answer is not a good SO answer.

Comment: @TimP Also, I wasn't trying to cause agro either; just trying to point out some of the conventions of SO as you are quite new to the site (judging by rep).

Comment: Ok, that's cool guys. I'll adjust the wording in my answer accordingly so it's self contained. Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

```
traits[row.names(traits)%in%species,]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can index by rownames as stored in `species` directly using the `[` subsetting function:

```
> traits[species, ]
    Tr1 Tr2 Tr3
sp1   1   0   1
sp2   1   0   0
```

In this instance you are indexing via a character vector instead of a numeric index vector or a logical vector. See `?"["` for more.